# onPause not called by hitting Powerbutton

Tags: java, android, onpause

if I hit the Powerbutton in my app while the app is currently running the `onPause` in not called. First question: Is this usual for Android?
I tried to call the`onPause` by setting an `onKeyListener`. Can I set this `onKeyListener` for all elements in the activity? E.g. I set it on my `realativeLayout`.

```
rLayout.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER))
            {
                onPause();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But this also didn't work. So now the main question: Do you have any possibility to call `onPause` if you hit the Powerbutton while the app is currently running? (Don't need to be an `onKeyListener`)

Comment: onPause should be called as part of the natural activity lifecycle when the phone is locked. Post your onPause method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As your activity enters the paused state, the system calls the
>   onPause() method

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

It's important to note that the app itself NEVER calls onPause itself because that would likely mess up the Activity's life cycle (which is managed by Android not the app). If the user presses the power button, the Activity will be paused by Android automatically, there's no need to do anything in your app.
If you think the onPause isn't called, please post the onPause code.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to call `onPause` before my phone goes into sleepmode, howsoever ...
Here is my `onPause`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    appactive = 0;
    lastappactive = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
}
```